# Is there a list of Punkbuster-free games anywhere?

Tags: technical-issues, punkbuster

I enjoy playing BF3, MW, etc, but Punkbuster always gives me a grief anytime there is an update.

I would like to know in advance which games use Punkbuster and which don't, as I will no longer be buying games that use it.

Where is the best place to find out what games will use Punkbuster before purchasing?

Comment: Punkbuster-free? That's going to be a *long* list. Let's start from the beginning: I'm *very* sure the original Computer Space and Pong (from the 1970ties) or, speaking only of FPSes, [The Colony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colony_%28video_game%29) from 1988 don't use Punkbuster.

Comment: When I used to play Warrock, Punkbuster always banned me for aimbotting because I was lagging -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://evenbalance.com/index.php?page=support.php) gives an overview of which games support Punkbuster.

Notice that you can turn off Punkbuster in some of these games, or set a search filter for servers having PB turned-off.

Comment: BF3 supports punkbuster free games. Cheats paradise mind but thems da breaks